# Strange SQLite behavior: increased execution time when adding AND statements to query that already has no results

Tags: sqlite

I found something strange when debugging a Python app that performs thousands of queries and it seemed to take WAY too long (half an hour, now it's down to 7 seconds).

I have a local table with relationships, `rxcui1` and `rxcui2` are indexed numerical values and `rela` is an indexed string. I'm looking to get all *rxcui1* when I have *rxcui2* and *rela*. Now I found that when I only search for *rxcui2* I very quickly get a result back—in the example an empty set. When I add to this same query an `AND rela = xy` the execution time goes way up, despite the search for *rxcui2* already turning up empty. See this timing:

```
sqlite> SELECT rxcui1 from rxnrel where rxcui2=29186;
CPU Time: user 0.000068 sys 0.000033
sqlite> SELECT rxcui1 from rxnrel where rxcui2=29186 AND rela IS NOT NULL;
CPU Time: user 0.000054 sys 0.000029
sqlite> SELECT rxcui1 from rxnrel where rxcui2=29186 AND rela IS NOT NULL AND rela='tradename_of';
CPU Time: user 0.119211 sys 0.018329
```

Why is this happening? The result comes back empty after the first restriction, why does SQLite even bother to check for the subsequent statements? I'm using SQLite 3.7.13 on OS X 10.9

---

### Update

**WOW!** I just deleted the index over `rela` and now it works as expected! Can anybody explain why this is happening? Maybe this is fixed in a more recent SQLite version?

```
sqlite> SELECT rxcui1 from rxnrel where rxcui2=29186 AND rela IS NOT NULL AND rela='tradename_of';
CPU Time: user 0.000064 sys 0.000028
```

---

### Update

I guess using `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` solves the mystery.

With index over *rela*:

```
sqlite> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT rxcui1 from rxnrel where rxcui2=29186 AND rela IS NOT NULL AND rela='tradename_of';
0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE rxnrel USING INDEX X_RXNREL_RELA (RELA=?) (~2 rows)
```

Without the *rela* index but the *rxcui2* index:

```
sqlite> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT rxcui1 from rxnrel where rxcui2=29186 AND rela IS NOT NULL AND rela='tradename_of';
0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE rxnrel USING INDEX X_RXNREL_RXCUI2 (RXCUI2=?) (~2 rows)
```

Comment: Show the output of EXPLAIN QUER PLAN (not EXPLAIN) for these queries.

Comment: Thanks @CL., that's solving the mystery!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the query plan it's now clear what happens. SQLite can only use one index per query (first thing I didn't know) and does not regard your query ordering as important (second thing I didn't know). Back in the MySQL days I used to optimize queries by "correctly" ordering the statements, but SQLite does not respect that and probably is right most of the time. But not in this case where it decides to use the *rela* index which I know is way less effective than the *rxcui2* index.

I did some test with a combined index over *rxcui2* and *rela* but it's not noticeably faster than only having an index over *rxcui2*. This is very specific to my use-case, my take-away is that I need to take a closer look at every concrete SQLite query if I want to make sure it's fast, it's not enough to make sure the first statement can use an index and then add more statements at will.